# Yosemite and character viewer

Tags: macos, internationalization, character-map

I just upgraded to Yosemite, I find that I cannot minimise the Character Viewer into the dock as I used to... is this normal?
It saved me a lot of trouble to have it pop-up every time I started the computer.
Or maybe there's a way to have it a login item?

Maybe [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196702/launching-character-viewer-aka-characterpalette-from-command-line) is related but I find this complex...

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're facing is that the Character Viewer is no longer global, but is now per-app, so if you open it in, for instance, Safari, then switch to Finder, it will vanish.
Open it again in Finder & its stored size, position & last viewed will be different.

The advantage is you can keep it open in 2 different apps at the same time [with the one attached to any backgrounded app hidden] & be working on 2 different things.
The downside would be if that's not what you want to do ;-)

Simplest way to activate it is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>  but there's no 'close' command other than clicking the red dot, or temporarily, by switching to another app.

Comment: Why is this better than when we could always have in in the dock in the past? What I'm asking is, why did they change this thinking it was an improvement?

Comment: "Why" doesn't have any answer that you could get from anywhere other than Apple. This is how it now is, for better or worse, depending on your working method.

Comment: For sure! They love fixing what isn't broken more and more... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any Character Viewer app that could be placed in the Dock (then again, I don't remember if I used this thing before Yosemite, though I think so). But in `Settings > Keyboard` you can find `Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar` so they are accessible. I agree it's handy at times, but to my knowledge, only apps and folders can be placed into the Dock.

Comment: It can be docked in 10.7, which I am running at the moment.  Character Viewer is in fact an app in system/library/input methods.